# Error using suiteanswer suggestion to combine multiple invoice pdfs into one and email

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I am getting an error when deploying the following script

```
function sendSevaredentEmails(){
var sResult = new Array();
 
 sResult = nlapiSearchRecord('transaction','customsearch1899'); //load an existing transaction saved search or create a search
 
 var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC \"-//big.faceless.org//report\" \"report-1.1.dtd\">\n";
   xml += "<pdfset>";
 
 for (var i = 0; sResult != null && i < sResult.length; i++) {
 var sColumns = sResult[i].getAllColumns();
  
  //generate invoice printout
  var pdfFile = nlapiPrintRecord('TRANSACTION', sResult[i].getValue(sColumns[0]),'PDF');
  
  //set target folder in file cabinet
  pdfFile.setFolder(483765);
  //Set Available without login to true
  pdfFile.setIsOnline(true);
  
  //store file in cabinet
  var fileID = nlapiSubmitFile(pdfFile);
  
  // load the file to get its URL
  var fileURL = nlapiLoadFile(fileID).getURL();

  var pdf_fileURL = nlapiEscapeXML(fileURL);

    xml += "<pdf src='"+ pdf_fileURL +"'/>";
 
 }
 
   xml += "</pdfset>";
   var consolidatedPDF = nlapiXMLToPDF(xml);
  
   nlapiSendEmail('-5', 'rspector@blackstoneind.com', "Subject", 'Body', null, null, null, consolidatedPDF);
}
```

I am getting the following error
`System UNEXPECTED_ERROR    8/22/2023   5:04 pm -System-    Cannot convert INVH8437 to java.lang.Integer (SYSTEM_LIBS$NSAPI$sys#758); ID: llmso2pi1v9yvv4a21klp`

INVH8437 is the first invoice number returned by the saved search so I know I'm getting that far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Log the result of `sResult[i].getValue(sColumns[0])`.  Are you getting the internal id or the invoice number here?

Comment: Hi Krypton,
I'm trying to get the output of that command using log.debug but am getting an error telling me that log is undefined. I can't figure out how to log that result in SuiteScript 1.0. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please disregard that last comment, I figured it out. sResult[i].getValue(sColumns[0]) returns the invoice number, not the internal ID.

Comment: OK, sounds like that might be your problem.  You need to pass the internal id into the `nlapiPrintRecord()` call for it to work.

Comment: That did the trick, passing the internal ID got the script to execute. Although now I end up with all of the invoices in the file cabinet instead of one pdf with all of the invoices, but that is a different issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you pass the ***internal ID*** of the invoice into your `nlapiPrintRecord()` call, not the invoice number.

Answer (score 0):

I added the internal id to column 0 of the saved search and the script ran successfully!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).